# typedef for a registering a constructor function in C

Tags: c, typedef

I need to register a constructor function (a function that creates some object). I'm using the following typedef:

```
typedef void * (sphactor_constructor_fn) (
    void *arg);
```

It works as long as the return type matches `void *`. However, the functions can return anything. For example, I'm unable to register a method like this:

```
pythonactor_t *
pythonactor_new(void *args)
```

I have to wrap it like this (just a cast to `void *`):

```
void *
pythonactor_construct(void *args)
{
    return (void *)pythonactor_new(args);
}
```

Is there any way around this wrapping so I can register the function as is?

Comment: `to register` register where? `I'm unable` You can't type it? What do  you mean by "unable"? What happens if you do?

Comment: cast to `sphactor_constructor_fn`?

Comment: This sounds like you are assuming some kind of a framework to work with.

Comment: How does this "registering a constructor" work?  You haven't shown or described it.  And have you tried casting to your typedef type when you do so?

Comment: The wrapper function is the legitimate way to do it. Casting the function pointer type to a different function pointer type would rely on undefined behavior. C11 6.3.2.3/8: _[...] If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined._.

Comment: Normally, you would write one constructor per type (as in any language with OO syntax support). What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: Casting was a good suggestion, @Dmitri, although it doesn't work just like that. However like this `(sphactor_constructor_fn *)&pythonactor_new` does work. A bit unintuitive, though

Answer (score 0):

Without using a wrapper function, your function needs to conform to the given function type:

```
void *pythonactor_new(void *args)
```

You won't have the compile time check on the returned type, however you can freely convert an object pointer to/from a `void *` without casting.

Comment: Yeah I know, but void is used to capture anything so I was hoping I could find a way to except the function as is. In C++ it work by just wrapping it in a templated method.

Comment: It seems the suggestion to just cast by @Dmitri does work. So your answer is correct but there's a better solution

Comment: @ArnaudLoonstra The cast only *appears* to work.  Calling a function through an incompatible pointer type invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).